# Embedded Nul(s) while loading data in R

Tags: python, r, sql-server, filezilla, data-loss

The data I am talking about was exported from SQL server as CSV and has ~2million rows. Later this was shared to me over Filezilla (as this was client's data). I was trying to load this CSV file into R environment and was facing the below warning message:

*Warning message:*
*In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :*
*embedded nul(s) found in input*

This is not just a warning message but I lost ~1.5million rows after loading the data. That means only 500K rows are non-null. All these 500K rows are in good shape and matched with the parent data with clients.

This is where the interesting part of the puzzle started. We made our clients upload the CSV back to SQL server in order to create a new table and checked the total rows (along with few other metrics). All the data was there, they did not even miss a single row.

The other threads on ***embedded nul(s)*** is helping to read the data without warning. But I don't want that. So I am asking your help to answer me below questions:

1. Is there a way to read the file with embedded nuls (even if they are nuls I have no issues, but want to read all 2million rows first)
2. Is there any possible security measure to convert most of the data to NULL while sharing the sensitive data with users? (may be my clients and I don't know about it and trying to solve a wrong problem)

**Note:**

- I tried loading the data in Python and Alteryx as well but the result is same
- There is no data loss as the file size matched exactly with what clients have given us
- Did not try loading the data on SQL server as I do not have it on my system, but the thing is I want the data on R/Python to do some analysis

Comment: Do you mean to say that the CSV file contains ASCII NUL (0x00) characters? That's quite unusual and would mess with a lot of utilities that were written in C because C uses NUL-terminated strings.

Comment: Is it possible that it's a UTF-16 encoded CSV file? In a UTF-16 encoded file every other byte would be 0x00 for English characters.